# how to get objects of calling thread with implements runnable?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Hello I have a question with my code. As you can see below, I have r.getBlink() under OnDraw() method. Is there a function to determine if the "s" thread calls the OnDraw(). I mean I tried this.getClass().getBlink() but it displays as an error. help please.

```
     public class main extends Activity {
          @Override
          public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(new BitmapView(this));
          }
    }

    class BitmapView extends View implements OnTouchListener{
          Circle r = new Circle();
          Circle s = new Circle();

          public BitmapView(Context context) {
          super(context);
                  this.setOnTouchListener(this);
          r.starter();
          s.starter();
}

public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    if (r.getBlink()==true){
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        r.setBlink(false);
    }
    else{
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        r.setBlink(true);
    }

    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
    canvas.drawCircle(r.getX(), r.getY(), 15, paint);
    invalidate();
 }
 class Circle implements Runnable{
    Random rnd=new Random();
    int x=rnd.nextInt(200), y=rnd.nextInt(200);
    boolean blink = false;
    public int getX(){  return this.x;  }
    public int getY(){  return this.y;  }
    public boolean getBlink() { return this.blink;  }
    public void setBlink(boolean b) { this.blink=b;  }

    public void starter(){
       Thread running=new Thread(this);
       running.start();
       x=rnd.nextInt(200);
       y=rnd.nextInt(200);
   }
   public void run(){
      while(true){
         try {
           Thread.sleep(rnd.nextInt(2000));
         } catch (Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Not sure of what you are trying to achieve here, if what you want is to identify which thread is calling the onDraw method you should be able to use the Thread.currentThread().getName(). Since the thread holds no data of what is doing you should explore using the Threadlocal class to store values for the thread, keep in mind that you need to call the remove method of the threadlocal class one you are certian that you dont need the value anymore. If you provides further details of what you intend to achieve i might be able to help a little more.

Answer (score -1):

```
Thread.currentThread().get Name();
```

-This method will give you the name of the currently executing thread object. I believe this is what you want.

Comment: I have tried Thread.currentThread().getName().getBlink() but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Try....Thread.currentThread().getBlink().....getName() part was just to retrieve the name

Comment: Tried that too, still no success.

Comment: Is it a compile time error?? if not, what value are you getting?? null??

Comment: the .getBlink is underlined with red. I would like to get the value of the blink object under the current thread. like r.getBlink or s.getBlink, is there a [function].getBlink?

Comment: Print Thread.currentThread().equals(r) and Thread.currentThread().equals(s) and see if it any case it is returning true...

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have set the thread with a name but it still says the name of the thread is 'main'